# Gtk Combo Box function missing arguments and expressions

Tags: c, user-interface, compiler-errors, gtk, gtk2

I'm trying to do a dropdown menu in GTK 2+, and the conclusion I reached Is that they are called "gtk_combo_box". However, whenever I try to compile, it gives me missing arguments in functions errors...

Here's the part of the code that matters:

```
  vbox3_field = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (hbox2), vbox3_field);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (hbox2), vbox3_field, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

  vbox3_sett = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (hbox2), vbox3_sett);

  ball_menu=gtk_combo_box_text_new ();
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText ball_menu, "1");
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText ball_menu, "2");
  gtk_combo_box_set_active (GtkComboBox *combo_box, 0);
  //g_signal_connect (ball_menu, "changed", G_CALLBACK (cb_ball_selection), gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text ());
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (vbox3_sett), ball_menu);
```

When I try to take the "GtkComboBoxText" out of the function argument, it still gives me a warning saying incompatible pointer type. (I declared "ball_menu" as GtkWidget *ball_menu).

The function is defined as follow in the GTK 2+ Reference site:

```
void
gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText *combo_box,
                                const gchar *text);
```

Here are the compilation results:

```
gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -lm
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:265:35: error: expected expression before ‘GtkComboBox’
   gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText ball_menu, "1");
                                   ^
main.c:265:35: error: too few arguments to function ‘gtk_combo_box_text_append_text’
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:74:0,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcomboboxtext.h:63:15: note: declared here
 void          gtk_combo_box_text_append_text     (GtkComboBoxText     *combo_box,
               ^
main.c:266:35: error: expected expression before ‘GtkComboBoxText’
   gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText ball_menu, "2");
                                   ^
main.c:266:35: error: too few arguments to function ‘gtk_combo_box_text_append_text’
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:74:0,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcomboboxtext.h:63:15: note: declared here
 void          gtk_combo_box_text_append_text     (GtkComboBoxText     *combo_box,
               ^
main.c:267:29: error: expected expression before ‘GtkComboBox’
   gtk_combo_box_set_active (GtkComboBox *combo_box, 0);
                             ^
main.c:267:29: error: too few arguments to function ‘gtk_combo_box_set_active’
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:72:0,
                 from main.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcombobox.h:101:15: note: declared here
 void          gtk_combo_box_set_active       (GtkComboBox     *combo_box,
               ^
```

Does anyone know the reason for this to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GtkComboBoxText ball_menu, "1");
```

does not have a valid cast / conversion, change to

```
gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(ball_menu), "1");
```

Comment: Ok, it worked, thanks.
Just a note, for gtk_combo_box_set_active the cast seems to be GTK_COMBO_BOX instead.